# What is the significance of the “ô” character in “rôle” in this work?

Tags: orthography, french, diacritics

In [this document](http://www.google.com.mx/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=stages%2bof%2bmilk%2bsouring&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http://www.jbc.org/content/24/3/191.full.pdf&ei=n-KgTtfALJH-sQKWsImUBQ&usg=AFQjCNGW8KsKJ4zgunf0erypIkWT92z7Kg) from 1916, on the last line of the first page is the word *rôle*. If context matters, the entire sentence is:

> As might readily be supposed, the control of the lactic acid fermentation plays a very important rôle in the manufacturing processes of all types of cheese.

This appears to be the only occurrence of this word or character in this document.

What is the meaning of the *^* mark? Is this an old writing convention that has been lost? If so, when was it used?

Comment: Did you look in a dictionary? What did it say?

Comment: @Hugo: Sure, and it gave me a proper definition (which I already knew), and showed both spellings, `rôle` and `role`.  It didn't explain the ^ character, though.

Comment: OK, thanks. At least that answers the `Or is it a typo or reproduction error?` part: "no, it's an alternate spelling".

Comment: Hotel is the same, the original spelling is with a circumflex but that's now archaic/pretentious.

Comment: IMHO, if it contains glyphs that aren't in the Sesame Street Alphabet Song, it is not spelled right for English. :-)

Answer (score 10):

It's because the word has an circumflex in the original French and kept that as a borrowed word. As foreign words become more common in English they tend to lose accents etc because English doesn't have them.

Comment: And insisting on the accents once they've been lost is more a symbol of the author's pretension than anything else.

Comment: And the circumflex has two, um . . . roles in French. One is to indicate a missing ‘s’. The other, as here, is to indicate the pronunciation.

Comment: I sometimes forget whether we use accents in English or not; I always find myself wondering why naïve gets a red squiggly under it.

Comment: Since we have unicode it's easy to use the diacriticals and where the correct pronunciation is unintuitive (as in *naïve*), I think it appropriate to put them in.

Comment: @z7sg - it's easier now to spell foreign names correctly with accents but as foreign words become English then they lose them. Role and naive are now pretty much English words. We don't spell sky as ský because that's what it was in Norse.

Comment: I don't think sky was ever written that way.

Comment: Indeed, _role_ sans accent would normally be pronounced a bit like _roll_, while _rôle_ sounds something like _haul_.

Comment: @niXar: are you talking about French? I think this is backwards. French has two 'o' vowels, one which sounds more like *roll* and one which sounds more like *haul*. The words *drôle, rôle* and *pôle* are pronounced with the *roll* vowel, and the words *sole, col* and *école* are pronounced with the *haul* vowel.