# What do the letters ï and ô mean?

Tags: orthography, vowels, diacritics, diaeresis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the distinction between “role” and “rôle” [with a circumflex]?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15488/what-is-the-distinction-between-role-and-role-with-a-circumflex)
>   [What is the significance of the “ô” character in “rôle” in this work?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45819/what-is-the-significance-of-the-o-character-in-role-in-this-work)
>   [What is the standard rule for using or not using hyphen and diaeresis on the words like reelect , reexamine, and cooperate?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66126/what-is-the-standard-rule-for-using-or-not-using-hyphen-and-diaeresis-on-the-wor)
>   [“Whereäs” as an alternative spelling of “whereas”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5603/whereas-as-an-alternative-spelling-of-whereas)

In an English science book written by an American, I saw some questionable spellings:

- *rôle*, with a circumflex accent (**^**) over the *o*;
- *coïncidence*, with a diaeresis (**¨**) over the first *i* but not the second.

Can anyone explain this? I am not a native speaker and don’t understand this culture.

Comment: Sounds like a math book.  Double and single dots are used to denote differentiation and sometimes the "hat" is used to denote vectors.

Comment: Voting to close as [general reference](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?word=role).

Comment: rôle and coïncidence are not mathematical accents.

Comment: See: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66126/what-is-the-standard-rule-for-using-or-not-using-hyphen-and-diaeresis-on-the-wor; note, though, that if you don't know that ˆ is called a circumflex and ¨ is called a diaeresis, then you can hardly go looking up how and when to use them. In other words, I don't see how this is general reference.

Comment: _Rôle_ is the original French spelling; it's a borrowed French word. The mark over the O is called a "circumflex accent," and in French it usually suggests that a consonant or a whole syllable has been lost -- the circumflex represents "compensatory lengthening". _Coïncidence_ is a training-wheels spelling of _coincidence_; the double dots are called a "diaresis" and indicate in English that the vowel they're on should be pronounced seperately from the vowel right before it -- the way the /ɪ/ in /ko.'ɪn.sə.dəns/ is. Another example is _coöperate_.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15488/what-is-the-distinction-between-role-and-role-with-a-circumflex

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Does an English author write these French in his English book
trying to hit that his French origin or hint he is more formal or something like that?

Comment: A foreign word often retains its original diacritics when adopted into English, as a sign of its foreignness; the writer gets credit for knowing a foreign language (or some of one), and the reader is reassured that his ignorance of the word is excusable. Eventually, when the word is felt to be fully "native" and there's nothing to be gained by keeping the diacritics, they disappear. The diaresis was common in the 19th Century, but is usually regarded as an affectation today.

Comment: @DavidVoyance I would probably describe the author as pretentious. However, it may not be his choice. I noticed that the _New Yorker_ magazine uses "reëlection" for President Obama's recent result.

Comment: @Marthaª Agree on 'don't see how this is GR'. However, look at this: https://www.google.com/search?q=co%F6perate Probably this can be closed for lack of background effort instead.

Comment: @Martha: certainly [simply searching the site for *role*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15488/) is not too much to ask for. The Wiktionary entry for [role](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/role) mentions *rôle*, too. In fact it's the very first thing it does. Likewise, it has a dedicated entry for [*coïncidence*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/co%C3%AFncidence), as do many dictionaries. You might or might not call that general reference, but I will go out on a limb and call it lack of research. Sorry, David. Closing as dupe.

Answer (score 2):

The mark over the *o* in *rôle* is a circumflex. In certain French words it can indicate a lost *s*, or show that the vowel is to be pronounced long. The mark over the *i* in *coϊncidence* is a dieresis, used to show that the vowel is to be pronounced separately from the previous one. They are hardly ever necessary in English, and I have not until now seen a dieresis used at all in *coincidence*.

Comment: I believe that *coïncidence* and *coïncident* occur only in French, where we got them from. The OED2 references those origins, but includes no citations in English with the diaeresis intact.

Comment: @tchrist you mustn't read the New Yorker, that uses diaereses on any word formed by combination if it brings two vowels together, as per *coïncidence*. Generally, if some will use a hyphen with a prefix, the New Yorker will use a diaersis.